# Storage of pseudo random bytes

Tags: php, mysql, random, hash

I have a 128 bit pseudo random secure code which I generate with a PHP function but I can't work out what datatype it needs to be stored in a MySQL table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Try the binary type. You need 16 bytes, so set the size to 16.

```
BINARY(16)
```

The varbinary type was mentioned, but since the value is always the same length, there is no need for it.

Comment: is `\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0` whatever you will see in a gui like phpmyadmin when you store the data or is that empty?

Answer (score 1):

I would use Varbinary to store it but you could use others.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`BINARY(16)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-varbinary.html) data type for this purpose.

Comment: Why `VARBINARY`? If it's always going to be 128 bits, wouldn't `BINARY` be better?